# Google analytics lost a week of reports

Tags: google-analytics

I've started a new website and I look at its analytics every day. Ever since I've started the app is not working properly, showing data differently from the web and sometimes even showing 0 accesses on an entire week

But today, I log in on my account and found that I have less than 50% accesses that yesterday

Poking around I find that the graphs only show the last 3 days

I select the date "this week", it shows the last 3 days (17, 18 and 19), I select the date "this month", it still shows the same 3 days I select the date "last week" doesn't matter

I can see that the website is loading data, so it can't be cache. What could possibly be going on?

Comment: Have you changed your filters anytime in the past week?  I believe changing the filters deletes data outside of your filter set, even if you return to your original filter.

Comment: No. I didn’t change anything. I’m just following what is going on. Where can I see what are filters? So o know not to mess with it

Comment: Filters are under the Admin menu and are helpful to hide certain traffic, like your own visits or internal company hits.

Comment: Found it. Like I said, no filters

Comment: If you are using GA4, there has been a bug that has been affecting historical data for GA4 properties. GA team are working on it.. from what i know, no data is lost  and they are working on restoring it, however it may take a few weeks to do so.